# Cannot login to Ubuntu 14.04 cannot start session

Tags: login, session

I performed a regular update on Ubuntu 14.04 and worked fine after restart, then on the next morning I could not login using my credentials! When I use CTRL+ALT+F1 I can log in normally... I changed the permissions of the home directory using `sudo chmod -R u+w /home/user` and tried to login again but it always give me the error message that it cannot start session.

I checked the permission with `ls -l /home` and the result is:

```
drwrxrwxr-x 47 (user) (user) 4096   14   11:57  (user)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution to my question, it is in the session; so the following solved it:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session
```

but obviously this solution needs an Internet connection pre-configured, now I will try to find a solution for offline use without re-installing Ubuntu.